# HTML5 Canvas 2d Flickering at the same point

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I made a simple animation in JavaScript using a HTML5 canvas for drawing. My problem is that the animation always flickers at the same point. Interestingly this is not happening at the time the animation gets reset.

So here's the code I use for drawing:

```
draw: function() {
    var canvas = background.ct; 
    canvas.clearRect(0,0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        var sX = startX+((SLOT_WIDTH+20)*i)+mod;
        drawCard(
                {x: sX,
                    y: startY,
                    color: "#0A5",
                    ctx: canvas});
        if (resetX == sX && mod != 0) //resets the animation
            {
                console.log('resetting at '+mod);
                mod = 0;
            }

        if ( i == 1 && resetX == 0) //get reset-point
            {
                resetX = startX+((SLOT_WIDTH+20)*i)+mod;
            }


    }
    mod++;

}
```

This is the drawCard function:

```
/*
 * Draw 1 Card where x/y is the center of the card
 */
 function drawCard(pos)
 {
if (!pos.x || !pos.y)
    return;

var c_top_left_x = pos.x - SLOT_WIDTH / 2;
var c_top_y = pos.y - SLOT_HEIGHT / 2;
var c_top_right_x = pos.x + SLOT_WIDTH / 2;
var c_bot_left_x = pos.x - SLOT_WIDTH / 2;
var c_bot_right_x = pos.x + SLOT_WIDTH / 2;
var c_bot_y = pos.y + SLOT_HEIGHT / 2;

var canvas = pos.ctx;
canvas.beginPath();
canvas.moveTo(c_top_left_x + RAD, c_top_y);
canvas.lineTo(c_top_right_x - RAD, c_top_y);
canvas.arcTo(c_top_right_x, c_top_y, c_top_right_x, c_top_y + RAD, RAD);
canvas.lineTo(c_bot_right_x, c_bot_y - RAD);
canvas.arcTo(c_bot_right_x, c_bot_y, c_bot_right_x - RAD, c_bot_y, RAD);
canvas.lineTo(c_bot_left_x + RAD, c_bot_y);
canvas.arcTo(c_bot_left_x, c_bot_y, c_bot_left_x, c_bot_y - RAD, RAD);
canvas.lineTo(c_top_left_x, c_top_y + RAD);
canvas.arcTo(c_top_left_x, c_top_y, c_top_left_x + RAD, c_top_y, RAD);
canvas.fillStyle = pos.color;

canvas.fill();

}
```

mod is the variable that is used for creating a motion.

The full source is at http://jsfiddle.net/Kafioin/ymddh/

Comment: You should get better with the debugger in your browser. If you'd used it, you have received an error from line 136 of index.html - line 30 of your jsfiddle. `background.cv2` is not defined. The call to append it to document.body therefore fails.

Comment: Ah no, this was just a leftover of the previous try - using a double-buffer. I already removed it and the double-buffer didn't change a thing :/

Comment: The problem is that there is this annoying flickering at the most left card. You can see it now at jsfiddle as I've corrected the mistake.

Comment: This doesn't fix your problem, but you can drop those `.lineTo()` calls from `drawCard` as the spec for `.arcTo` requires the browser to add in a straight line from the last point in the path to the starting point in the arc anyway: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas_CR/#dom-context-2d-arcto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove/fix this line in `drawCard` the flickering will stop:

```
if (!pos.x || !pos.y) return;
```

The flicker occurs when pos.x==0.  Since !0 is true your draw is not executed for that animation loop.

Comment: Ah hell. I always hung myself up on the easy things. Thank you! Guess I would never found that :x